# What is the purpose on adding auth sign in session?

Tags: php, security, session, authentication, token

```
session structure:

user_info:
    uid='1'
    username='admin'
user_auth_sign:
    0943jjkfgb3h89hugr908ehgshg98hs
```

When coding with the user auto login system using php,the session stores two parts of info,the first is the user_info,and the second is user_auth_sign,like the code showing above.

When performing user auto login,it will use the user_auth_sign string stored in session compared with the value made by using user_info stored in session using this function,like the following:

```
function data_auth_sign($user_info) {
    ksort($user_info);
    $code = http_build_query($user_info);
    $sign = sha1($code); //user_auth_sign
    return $user_auth_sign;
}
```

The code below is how I check if a user can be auto logged in:

```
function auto_login(){
    return $_SESSION['user_auth_sign'] == data_auth_sign($_SESSION['user_info']) ? $_SESSION['user_info']['uid']) : 0;
}
```

Where I'm getting confused is why to use the user_auth_sign string comparsion,some people tell me it is for purpose of preventing from session faking,but how?

Another thing is if some one gained access to the user_auth_sign() function,he will know how the user auth sign generated and he can make a valid user_sign,which means he will be login as someone else if he knows the username,uid?So this code is bad?

Comment: What is this _system_ you are talking about?

Comment: And “auto login” usually refers to a system where the user gets automatically logged in when visiting the site later, by a specific cookie value – but since this system seems to rely on a session value (and therefor won’t work any more once the expired session is deleted by the garbage collector), I won’t call this an “auto login”.